# Angular 9 - How to refresh form page after HttpClient POST?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 9 application and am having some trouble getting my page to refresh after a HttpClient POST request.

Here is my form and form component:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit-button">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>

----------------------------------------------------------

@Component({
    selector: 'my-form',
    templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private apiService: APIService, private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    save(myForm: NgForm) {
        this.apiService.addSomething(myForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
            // Not sure what to do here to get the page to reload.
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried doing a `this.apiService.getSomething()` call (which is the REST endpoint for getting all the things). I have tried doing something like `this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate('/'))` that I saw in a different question here on SO but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For good measure, here is my api service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class APIService {
    private SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
    };

    // Get all the things
    public getAllThings() {
        return this.httpClient.get(this.SERVER_URL + '/things').pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    // Add a thing
    public addSomething(thing: ThingType) {    
        return this.httpClient
            .post(this.SERVER_URL + '/things', submission, this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
}
```

Edit: My goal is to show a success message (perhaps, near the submit button) indicating that the form has been submitted and to clear the form out.

Comment: Do you want to empty the form? What's the purpose of refreshing the page?

Comment: Yea, the main purpose is to show a "Success" message that the form has been filled out and to clear out the form. I'll modify my question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the form, use the following:

```
myForm.reset()
```

Create a variable for show success message and have a conditional element in the template.

```
isSuccess = false;

save(myForm: NgForm) {
   this.apiService.addSomething(myForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
       form.reset();
       this.isSuccess = true;
   });
}
```

Template:

```
<p *ngIf="isSuccess">Successful</p>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `this.router.navigate([''])` should be fine.

But angular disables the navigation on same url.

You yon enable this feature in your `app-routing.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: This is helpful because I had another issue that can be solved using this.